# Possible to share JS file across projects in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I can see how you can share a JS file between LWC components in a single project, but what if I want to create a JS library of functionality to use across multiple projects? Can it sit in some repository in SF and get imported when you create a new project in VS code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way a package can sit in Salesforce is to be an Unlocked Package. You can specify the Unlocked Package as a dependency in a new project, thus giving you access to the common shared code. However, be aware that your repository/local device won't have the code directly; you'll have to install the package before starting your work in a new Scratch Org. If you want to have the code available locally, use Git and "fork" the repo. You can pull updates to the core code in to your repo from an upstream forked project.